# str_detect is not working when I try to simulate infinite monkey problem (maybe I don't know how to use it )

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to use str_detect, but it returns "FALSE" when the pattern I'm looking for actually is in the string.
Here is a code:

`monkey=paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = " ")`

When I run this line, I get something like this

`[1] "L Y W G Q R W G X L"`

But when I try to find the pattern `YW`, for example, str_detect returns FALSE. Maybe I don't understand really well how str_detect works, I used

`str_detect(monkey, "YW")`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Because all the letters are separated by space.  You need `"Y\\s+W"` or simply `"Y W"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to look for any character that is 'Y' or 'W', wrap it inside square brackets or else it will be looking for that case where 'Y' followed by 'W' which didn't exist in the string as there is a space character between Y and W

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(monkey, "[YW]")
[1] TRUE
```

---

If we really wanted to check the pattern 'Y' followed by 'W', specify the space and use a `fixed` pattern (should be faster) - by default it is in `regex` mode

```
str_detect(monkey, fixed("Y W"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Or if we are not sure whether there are spaces or not, specify `\\s*` i.e. zero or more spaces

```
str_detect(monkey, "Y\\s*W")
#[1] TRUE
```

which will match `"YW"`, `"Y W"`, or `"Y      W"` etc.

#### data

```
monkey <- "L Y W G Q R W G X L"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try a `utf8ToInt` way like below:

- If you want to detect both `"Y"` and `"W"` in `monkey`

```
all(utf8ToInt("YW") %in% utf8ToInt(monkey))
```

- If you want to detect any of `"Y"` and `"W"` in `monkey`

```
any(utf8ToInt("YW") %in% utf8ToInt(monkey))
```